# Assign or Execute a controller action to a url if subdomain is found

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-routing

If a URL will contain a sub domain like `http://raddyx.sharemybucket.com./` then I want to execute a controller action for that and the sub domain as its parameter.For Ex for above URL I want execute `Users` controller and `profile` action with `raddyx` as its parameter.

Ex : `http://raddyx.sharemybucket.com/` for this I want to execute

```
http://sharemybucket.com/users/profile/raddyx
```

Comment: I want to show user profile page for this i want to use username as sub domain.

Comment: This might best be solved with rewrite rules in your web server config (e.g. .htaccess) instead of through Cake routes.

Comment: Something like - `RewriteRule ^(http://)?([A-Za-z]+).sharemybucket.com/?$ http://sharemybucket.com/users/profile/$2 [L,NC]`